# How to find tweets with hashtags using TwitterUtils and Streaming?

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to find tweets with a hashtag.

The problem is, instead of tweets, it is displaying sometimes a time,
like: `Time: 1450631964000 ms`, and sometimes nothing.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Set up Spark environment
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags").setMaster("local[2]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

// Launch Twitter Receiver
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

// Transformations
val statuses = stream.map(status => status.getText())
val t = statuses.filter(status => status contains "#Spark")

// Action!
t.print()
```

Why does `t.print` not print the tweets?

Answer (score 1):

`print` will show up to 10 items for each of your intervals, which is set to `Seconds(2)`. It displays this in the format of

```
TIMESTAMP
-----
RECORD 1
...
RECORD 10
```

It will always print out the timestamp and dashes, even if there there is nothing in the `DStream` So, what is most likely happening is that nobody is tweeting with that hashtag in the period you are looking at. Otherwise, the code looks fine.